# No "Android DDMS" in Tools->Android menu?

Tags: android-studio, ddms

In IDEA I can open DDMS from inside it via Tools->Android menu. However in Androdi Studio there is no such entry.

How can I open DDMS from Android Studio? Is this feature ported from IDEA to Android Studio?

Comment: It's still there, it is now just called `Android Device Monitor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDMS is [apparently](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects-cmdline.html) still there, in sdk/tools/ddms (can be started from terminal).

Tools>Android>Android Device Monitor apparently *contains* a DDMS.

They look different, but the latter seems to have at least everything provided by the former, which seems to lack a File Explorer? Presumably the former is a fall-back until the latter is completely stable?

Disclaimer: just starting to explore this.